# Removing HTML element styles via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, styles

I'm trying to replace an element's inline style tag value. The current element looks like this:

```
`<tr class="row-even" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%; position: relative; -moz-background-clip: -moz-initial; -moz-background-origin: -moz-initial; -moz-background-inline-policy: -moz-initial;" id="0000ph2009-06-10s1s02">`
```

and I'd like to remove all that style stuff so that it's styled by it's class rather than it's inline style. I've tried delete element.style; and element.style = null; and element.style = ""; to no avail. My current code breaks at these statement. The whole     function looks like:
function unSetHighlight(index){

```
if(index < 10)
index = "000" + (index);
else if (index < 100)
  index = "000" + (index);
  else if(index < 1000)
    index = "0" + (index);
    if(index >= 1000)
      index = index;
    
var mainElm = document.getElementById('active_playlist');
var elmIndex = "";

for(var currElm = mainElm.firstChild; currElm !== null; currElm = currElm.nextSibling){
  if(currElm.nodeType === 1){

  var elementId = currElm.getAttribute("id");

  if(elementId.match(/\b\d{4}/)){
    
    elmIndex = elementId.substr(0,4);
    
            
    if(elmIndex == index){
      var that = currElm;
      //that.style.background = position: relative;
      }
    }
  }
}
       
clearInterval(highlight);
alert("cleared Interval");
that.style.background = null;

alert("unSet highlight called");
}
```

the clearInterval works but the alert never fires and the background stays the same. What's the problem?

---

```
function unSetHighlight(index){  
  alert(index);  
  if(index < 10)  
    index = "000" + (index);  
    else if (index < 100)  
      index = "000" + (index);  
      else if(index < 1000)  
        index = "0" + (index);  
        if(index >= 1000)  
          index = index;  
        
    var mainElm = document.getElementById('active_playlist');
    var elmIndex = "";
  
    for(var currElm = mainElm.firstChild; currElm !== null; currElm = currElm.nextSibling){
      if(currElm.nodeType === 1){

      var elementId = currElm.getAttribute("id");

      if(elementId.match(/\b\d{4}/)){
        
        elmIndex = elementId.substr(0,4);
        alert("elmIndex = " + elmIndex + "index = " + index);
        
                
        if(elmIndex === index){
          var that = currElm;
          alert("match found");
          }
        }
      }
    }
        
    clearInterval(highlight);
    alert("cleared Interval");
    that.removeAttribute("style");
    
    //that.style.position = "relative";
    //reColor();
    alert("unSet highlight called");
}
```

Comment: Tried removeAttribute("style"), still no luck. I'm using setInterval to cycle through background colors to (try to) create a pulse effect. I'll try writing up some other style classes to try answer 4. Any other ideas? My current code is posted below...

Answer (score 199, accepted):

you can just do:

```
element.removeAttribute("style")
```

Comment: Or `element.style.cssText = null`, which does much the same.

Comment: @mrec not exactly the same, in your case an element still has empty `style` attribute

Comment: This answers the OP's question -- remove all inline style and fallback to stylesheet rules, but...it also blows away all the inline styles. If you want to selectively remove rules from the inline styles, @sergio's answer below (actually, davidjb's comment on that answer) is more useful.

Answer (score 76):

In JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("id").style.display = null;
```

In jQuery:

```
$("#id").css('display',null);
```

Comment: The first line of code appears to either error in Internet Explorer (<9) with ``Invalid argument`` or cause the element to disappear entirely in IE >= 9.  Setting ``getElementById("id").style.display = ''``, being the empty string, appears to work across browsers.

Comment: in jQuery the correct way to remove a style is `$("#id").css('display', '');`

Comment: This got me close, but it wasn't null, but 'none' that worked, e.g. `$("#id").css('display','none');`

Comment: display:none has nothing to do with this question or answer. That's for hiding elements.

Comment: There is also `CSSStyleDeclaration.removeProperty()` which imho is a lot cleaner than a null assignment. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/removeProperty

Answer (score 12):

```
getElementById("id").removeAttribute("style");
```

if you are using jQuery then

```
$("#id").removeClass("classname");
```

Comment: Those two code snippets do wildly different things. Only the first has anything to do with the question.

Answer (score 5):

The class attribute can contain multiple styles, so you could specify it as

```
<tr class="row-even highlight">
```

and do string manipulation to remove 'highlight' from element.className

```
element.className=element.className.replace('hightlight','');
```

---

Using jQuery would make this simpler as you have the methods

```
$("#id").addClass("highlight");
$("#id").removeClass("hightlight");
```

that would enable you to toggle highlighting easily

Comment: Another advantage of defining .highlight in your style sheet is you can change exactly how a "highlight" is displayed by just changing one line of CSS and not making any Javascript changes at all. If you're _not_ using JQuery, adding and removing a class is still pretty simple: /*on*/ theElement.className += ' highlight'; /*off*/ theElement.className = theElement.className.replace(/\b\s*highlight\b/, ''); (By defining .element in CSS, it automatically stays the _same_ everywhere, too.)

Comment: Oops, forgot possibility class is specified more than once. To handle that case too, add 'g' flag to the regular expression: theElement.className = theElement.className.replace(/\/b\s*highlight\b/g, '');

Comment: use classlist node property instead of className

Answer (score 5):

**Remove removeProperty**

```js
var el = document.getElementById("id");
el.style.removeProperty('display')

console.log("display removed" + el.style["display"])
console.log("color " + el.style["color"])
```

```html
<div id="id" style="display:block;color:red">s</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use

`particular_node.classList.remove("<name-of-class>")`

For native javascript

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery, you can use

```
$(".className").attr("style","");
```

Answer (score 1):

Completly removing style, not only set to NULL

```
document.getElementById("id").removeAttribute("style")
```