# how to remove css property using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

is it possible to remove a CSS property of an element using JavaScript ?
e.g. I have `div.style.zoom = 1.2`, 
now i want to remove the zoom property through JavaScript ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [removing html element styles via javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040402/removing-html-element-styles-via-javascript)

Answer (score 361, accepted):

You have two options:

**OPTION 1:**

You can use [removeProperty method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/removeProperty). It will remove a style from an element.

```
el.style.removeProperty('zoom');
```

**OPTION 2:**

You can set it to the default value:

```
el.style.zoom = "";
```

The effective zoom will now be whatever follows from the definitions set in the stylesheets (through link and style tags). So this syntax will only modify the local style of this element.

Comment: … along with user CSS and the browser default styles.

Comment: I understood the OP to mean that they wanted to make it as though they had not set the style property of the element, which is exactly what you've provided. I tried using el.style.removeProperty('zoom'); (or 'fill', actually, in my case) that seems to do the same thing in IE, and get ignored by the other browsers. For some reason I was surprised to find that setting it to a blank string has the same effect and seems to work on all (recent versions of) the browsers.

Comment: Is this behaviour specified anywhere in a standard? I can't find it :-(

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh yes it's documented, see this answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/7901886/700206

Comment: I will use method 1 for CSS variables

Answer (score 130):

**removeProperty** will remove a style from an element.

Example:

> div.style.removeProperty('zoom');

MDN documentation page:
[CSSStyleDeclaration.removeProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/removeProperty)

Comment: This is very nice, because styles from classes will be kept applied.

Comment: Note: Multi-word property names are hyphenated and not camel-cased.

Answer (score 31):

```
div.style.removeProperty('zoom');
```

Answer (score 13):

```
element.style.height = null;
```

output:

```
<div style="height:100px;"> 
// results: 
<div style="">
```

Comment: It seems that setting style to null does not work in IE11.

Comment: Why someone should care of `IE` browsers? I intentionaly ignore them already for years.

Comment: @T.Todua Is it necessary to use an inline code-block for a browser name? But yes, I completely agree - Microsoft has stopped supporting the browser since 2016.

Comment: Yeah, it **was** trash, anyways. ( But IE is still supported on my PC, no jokes, but still ended the support for it :/ )

Answer (score 10):

You can use the styleSheets object:

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.removeProperty("zoom");
```

Caveat #1:  You have to know the index of your stylesheet and the index of your rule.

Caveat #2:  This object is implemented inconsistently by the browsers; what works in one may not work in the others.

Comment: This seems really brittle. Won't it break whenever your indices change?

Comment: Yep.  That's exactly what caveat #1 says.

Comment: My Chrome 26 doesn't have `CSSStyleRule.prototype.removeProperty` =( In fact `CSSStyleRule` doesn't have any methods. =(

Comment: `CSSStyleSheet.prototype.removeRule` to the rescue.

Comment: @Rudie, isn't it `CSSStyleSheet.prototype.deleteRule`?

Comment: @roka Both seem to exist in Chrome. Don't know if they're the same. Docs anywhere?

Comment: This answer is incorrect, the question was to remove a style only for an element.  Maybe it could be updated to start out with var someElement...do something with someElement...

Comment: Before you spammed your -1's all over this page, @Lee, did you actually try any of these answers in a browser?  I ask because this answer does exactly what the OP wanted, albeit with the caveats that I mentioned.  There is more than one way to skin a cat, even if it's a way that you're not familiar with.

Comment: @james.garriss I'm "spamming" because you think your answer is better than it is?  This is not a mission of negativity, I also spent time editing a couple answers for clarity and improvement. I'm also not against alternative answers, sometimes different tradeoffs are needed.  The problem is your answer is more complex for no reason I can see, and I can't think of any scenario where it would be considered a best practice.  If there's data to the contrary I'm not thinking of, by all means share it, I have no problem changing my vote.

Comment: Ah, well, at least now you're admitting that the answer isn't incorrect after all.  Just complex.

Comment: @james.garriss You seem to prefer thin skinned comments to constructive collaboration.  So be it, to avoid confusion as to what I'm "admitting", I hereby judge your answer to be officially wrong, with the justification being bad practices should be removed from any source code repo where they are found.

Comment: LOL.  Sure.  Whatever.

Answer (score 5):

You can try finding all elements that have this class and setting the "zoom" property to "nothing".

If you are using jQuery javascript library, you can do it with `$(".the_required_class").css("zoom","")`

Edit: Removed this statement as it turned out to not be true, as pointed out in a comment and other answers it has indeed been possible since 2010.

False: *there is no generally known way for modifying stylesheets from JavaScript.*

Comment: Yes, there is. Modifying stylesheets programatically though javascript isn't hard. It works cross-browser with great performance and really makes sense when changing one property that should be the same on a bunch of elements. As was the case Jan 2010 as well. Here's a brief example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927706/how-do-you-modify-properties-of-a-large-amount-of-elements-in-a-good-way/14930638#14930638

Comment: Clox: Adding stylesheets that override some property programmatically - of course! Modifying the ones already loaded - Haven't heard of it.

Comment: Is it meant to be css() rather than attr(). Or is it perhaps attr() in IE?

Comment: it should actually be `css`, not `attr`, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this in jQuery by saying `$(selector).css("zoom", "")`

Answer (score 0):

actually, if you already know the property, this will do it...

for example:

```
<a href="test.html" style="color:white;zoom:1.2" id="MyLink"></a>

    var txt = "";
    txt = getStyle(InterTabLink);
    setStyle(InterTabLink, txt.replace("zoom\:1\.2\;","");

    function setStyle(element, styleText){
        if(element.style.setAttribute)
            element.style.setAttribute("cssText", styleText );
        else
            element.setAttribute("style", styleText );
    }

    /* getStyle function */
    function getStyle(element){
        var styleText = element.getAttribute('style');
        if(styleText == null)
            return "";
        if (typeof styleText == 'string') // !IE
            return styleText;
        else  // IE
            return styleText.cssText;
    }
```

Note that this only works for inline styles... not styles you've specified through a class or something like that...

Other note: you may have to escape some characters in that replace statement, but you get the idea.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick - setting the inline style to normal for zoom:

> $('div').attr("style", "zoom:normal;");

Comment: The question was how to remove a style, this answer will destroy all styles that exist and replace them with the one new entry.

Answer (score -4):

**To change all classes for an element:**

```
document.getElementById("ElementID").className = "CssClass";
```

**To add an additional class to an element:**

```
document.getElementById("ElementID").className += " CssClass";
```

**To check if a class is already applied to an element:**

```
if ( document.getElementById("ElementID").className.match(/(?:^|\s)CssClass(?!\S)/) )
```

Comment: The question was how to remove a style, this answer has nothing to do with that.