# How to override border:none?

Tags: css

I'm working with some thoroughly awful third-party software and needing to overwrite their CSS styling via an external CSS file.

They've set `border: none` on all form fields, but I'd like to have the input fields just use the browser's default styling.

How can I override the `border: none` so that the form fields are styled as if no `border` property was set?

Comment: There's the `!important` override if you really want to force a style on something.

Comment: Try either of `border: inherit` or `border: transparent`. One of them should work.

Answer (score 7):

Style the exceptions as `border: inherit`.

This will override the most recent border rule.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the value to nothing, if that desnt work, you could try this:
[how to remove css property using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027935/how-to-remove-css-property-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me for a nested :before class

```
    .vdr.active:before {
        outline: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming they aren't styling the input fields inline:

```
input {
    border: 1px solid #999 !important;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the heads up about inline. However, the OP did say they wanted the default borders back.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, there is no way in CSS to say that browser defaults be applied. For example, if any CSS rule sets a border on an element, then you can’t say “ignore that rule”; you can only set your own rule that overrides it (if you define your rule so that it wins in the cascade).

In practice, the following creates a border that is close to the defaults of popular browsers:

```
input { border: solid 1px #ddd; border-top-color: #aaa; padding: 2px; }
```

You may need to modify the selector (or even use `!important`) in order to win a setting in another stylesheet.