# Remove classname from element with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, classname

I found the following regex from another Stack Overflow question: [Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

And have used it in part of my script with success, however in another it seems to be failing.

I threw together a very minimalist test case on jsFiddle, and it is also failing:

http://jsfiddle.net/ew47Y/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="foo" id="foo">
    hello
</div>​
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     foo = document.getElementById('foo');
     foo.className += ' bar foobar';
     alert(foo.className);
     foo.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)bar(?!\S)/ , '' )
     alert(foo.className);
})​
```

Comment: I am confused by the mixture of jQuery and non-jQuery to do jQuery simplistic things

Comment: I'm writing a library and I find it bad practice to make one library require another.

Comment: please check this answer [Remove and add css class using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33434902/2466310)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That's because `replace` doesn't actually modify the string you call it on; rather, it returns a new string. So:

```
     foo.className = foo.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)bar(?!\S)/ , '' )
```

(By the way, you don't actually need to do this in raw JavaScript, since jQuery objects offer a `removeClass` method: http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/. So you could write:

```
     $('#foo').removeClass('bar');
```

or:

```
     $(foo).removeClass('bar');
```

)

Comment: Pure JS function: `function removeClass(e,c) {e.className = e.className.replace( new RegExp('(?:^|\\s)'+c+'(?!\\S)') ,'');}`

Comment: If you want to remove all the occurrences of a class name use the [`g` modifier](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp) at the end of the regular expression, like this: `foo.className.replace(/(^|\s)bar(?!\S)/g ,'')`. By the way, the use of the [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html) `(?:)` is not neccessary here.

Comment: Note that the use of the [word boundary metacharacter `\b`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), like: `foo.className.replace(/\bbar\b/g ,'')`, is not suitable here, because the word boundary occurs also between a word character `[A-Za-z0-9_]` and the dash `-` character. Therefore a class name e.g. *'different-bar-class'* would also be replaced resulting in *'different--class'*. However, as opposed to the above solutions, the "`\b`" solution doesn't remove the whitespace character `\s` before the class name, so a string e.g. *'firstbar bar'* will end up as *'firstbar '*.

Comment: @Adam: I have no idea what you're talking about. Your comment is the only place on this page that even mentions `\b`, so you hardly need to explain why it's inappropriate. And the use of a group *is* necessary; your personal preference for capturing groups `(...)` over non-capturing groups `(?:...)` is not of interest to anyone else.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I mainly meant to point out that the solution above (as opposed to the also possible "`\b`" solution) removes the whitespace which could be unwanted. I have rewritten this as an answer. We can now delete these last 3 superfluous comments here.

Comment: The double negation in the look-ahead `(?!\S)` seems unnecessary. I would rather use `(?=\s|$)`, seems clearer.

Answer (score 22):

Don't forget about `classList`.

`el.classList.remove('boop');`

http://jsfiddle.net/yXQL3/

Comment: not working (only) on IE 8, 9 and Opera Mini 8 http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist

Answer (score 6):

```
foo.className = foo.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)bar(?!\S)/ , '' );
```

or with jQuery (which you seem to be using):

```
foo.removeClass( 'bar' );
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a solution which use the [word boundary metacharacter `\b`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
foo.className.replace(/\bbar\b/g ,'');
```

This can suite somebody, but be aware the word boundary occurs also between a word character `[A-Za-z0-9_]` and the dash `-` character. Therefore a class name e.g. *'different-bar-class'* would also be replaced resulting in *'different--class'*. However, as opposed to the above solutions, the "`\b`" solution doesn't remove the whitespace character `\s` before the class name, which may be desired, so a string e.g. *'firstbar bar'* will end up as *'firstbar '*.