# Hide class pseudo-elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

How to show/hide class :before and :after pseudo elements with JavaScript?

I have arrows on both sides of div. Below is arrows style

```
 .edit-wrap:before,
 .edit-wrap:after {
     @media (max-width: 768px) {
         content: '';
         ....
     }
 }
```

I want to hide them, if, for example, there is no scroll bar in the element. And show otherwise

```
var scrollableElement = document.getElementById('scrollable-element');
if(scrollableElement.scrollWidth>scrollableElement.clientWidth){
               //display arrows
            } else{
               //hide arrows
            }
```

**I am not using JQuery**

Comment: by toggling `edit-wrap` class?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use CSS and JavaScript here.

CSS

```
.hide-before:before, .hide-after:after { display:none; }
```

JavaScript

```
var scrollableElement = document.getElementById('scrollable-element');

if (scrollableElement.scrollWidth>scrollableElement.clientWidth) {
   scrollableElement.classList.add('hide-after','hide-before');
} else {
   scrollableElement.classList.remove('hide-after','hide-before');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may remove the class which makes use of the pseudo classes `:before` and `:after`. With javascript you can achieve this by using the `className` property (assuming there are no other classes for the target).

```
var scrollableElement = document.getElementById('scrollable-element');
if (scrollableElement.scrollWidth > scrollableElement.clientWidth) {
    document.getElementById('yourElementId').className = 'edit-wrap';
} else {
    document.getElementById('yourElementId').className = '';
}
```

If you want to remove the specific class, you should have a look to `classList`, which is [supported by most modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=classList).

```
var scrollableElement = document.getElementById('scrollable-element');
if (scrollableElement.scrollWidth > scrollableElement.clientWidth) {
    document.getElementById('yourElementId').classList.add('edit-wrap');
} else {
    document.getElementById('yourElementId').classList.remove('edit-wrap');
}
```

Another approach for older browsers would be using [regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9959811).

Comment: @cale_b +1 for the suggested improvement. I added an example which is using `classList` and linked an already answered question on SO which uses regular expressions to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add, for example, .hide-pseudo class to element and edit your styles like this:

```
.edit-wrap.hide-pseudo:before,
.edit-wrap.hide-pseudo:after {
    disply: none;
}
```

Comment: *how* do you add the class?