# Javascript remove elements styling

Tags: javascript, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to remove css property using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027935/how-to-remove-css-property-using-javascript)

I'm modifying an elements overflow with js, when I do this:

```
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
```

The element becomes:

```
<body style="overflow: hidden;"></body>
```

Afterwards I want to turn the element back to:

```
<body style=""></body>
```

I don't want to change the overflow to anything, just remove the overflow from the element styles so that it falls back to the style.css. I tried:

```
document.body.style.overflow = '';
```

Which doesn't do anything. How can this be done?

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2027935/944681)

Comment: Seems like some kind of pilot error here, because this should've worked exactly as you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can just do this

```
document.body.setAttribute('style','');
```

Comment: OP wanted to remove just `overflow`, not all styles..

Answer (score 1):

Just clear the `style` attribute like this:

```
document.body.setAttribute("style", "");
```

Remember, CSS can come from many parts (a style attribute, an external stylesheet, an HTML tag and javascript)!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're only trying to change the current property (even by simply unsetting it), this will cause a problem. The issue seems to be that an empty-string is not considered a legitimate value for a CSS property, and, as such is not added to the `style` attribute.

In Chromium this can be worked around, but only be explicitly declaring a new value for the property, even if only by using the `auto` keyword. With that in mind, one approach is below:

```
var propStates = {
    // define the states, I'm only using two for a 'toggle'
    // approach, adjust to taste.
    'overflow': ['hidden', 'auto'],
    'display': ['block', 'auto']
}

function removeCSSProperty(el, prop) {
    if (!el || !prop) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        // el can be either a node-reference *or* a string containing
        // the id of the element to adjust
        el = el.nodeType == 1 ? el : document.getElementById(el);
        var current = window.getComputedStyle(el, null)[prop];
        el.style[prop] = propStates[prop][0] == current ? propStates[prop][1] : propStates[prop][0];
    }
}

document.getElementById('adjust').onclick = function() {
    removeCSSProperty('test', 'overflow');
};​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/49b5h/).

This approach requires the browser to understand the `window.getComputedStyle()` function, IE <9 is *not* supported (though it does have `currentStyle` which seems much the same in effect).