# what's the correct way to remove/reset a css property via javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to remove css property using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027935/how-to-remove-css-property-using-javascript)

I have this javascript:

```
var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
div.style.width = '300px';
div.style.height = '200px';
...
```

and so on...

Later on I am faced with the need of removing a property 
(not changing its value, really removing meaning: like I had not set that before)

I coded something like this:

1. div.style.height = undefined;
2. div.style.height = null;
3. div.style.height = '';

Only solution n.3 seems to work but even so... I am not sure this is the correct way to do it (I am only using chrome to test this)

Does anybody know what's the correct way ? which works across all proper browsers ?

Thanks

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027935/how-to-remove-css-property-using-javascript ... Basically "" will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "correct way". Microsoft once invented style.removeAttribute(), but it's not supported. The best way is to set it to the standard-value.

**Edit:** As dystroy mentioned, setting it to "" resets it in all browsers, so that would be the best way.

Comment: Set it to '' seems to reset it to default on all browsers.

Comment: @looper sounds like yours is the 'correct' answer. I will choose it unless somebody comes with a more comprehensive one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `inherit` or `initial` value. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#common-keywords

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
div.style.height = "auto"
```

Comment: Keep in mind the initial value may not have been `auto`. Some other value may have been specified.

Comment: But if the question says that he wants to _remove_ the value then it's not reseted to the original value, but to "auto". Of course "auto" applies only to height.

Comment: Not only height, but at least height, agreed.

Answer (score 1):

I have just created a fiddle with the following code

HTML

```
 <div id="foo" style="height: 100px;"></div>
```

CSS

```
#foo {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;   
}
```

JavaScript

```
var el = document.getElementById("foo");
el.style.height = "auto";
```

Setting the property to auto actually sets the style attribute on the element to

```
<div id="foo" style="height: auto;"></div>
```

and overrides the css height property applied to `#foo`. To reset a style, as mentioned by others set the element's style property to an empty string

```
el.style.height = "";
```

Fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/gea3F/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, another option might be to use `getComputedStyle` to get the current style property, and recall that value when a variable needs to be reset.

```
var style = getComputedStyle(div);

div.origWidth = style. getPropertyValue("width");
div.origHeight = style. getPropertyValue("height");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle

Answer (score -1):

I'd use the removeAttribute() function from the document

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").removeAttribute("height")
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if the height is given by CSS.