# How do you modify properties of a large amount of elements in a good way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a large table currently consisting of 95x120=11400 TD's and would like to dynamically edit properties such as height and background-color for all the cells from a certain row or 
column, or even a bunch of rows/columns. I want to do this in order to make the user able to resize rows/columns among other things.
What would be a good way of getting that done?

All the TD's in my table does by the way have unique class for row/col eg row1, row2, row3, col1, col2, col3 added dynamically while the table is built up though Javascript.

Comment: Get a group of elements you want to act on, iterate through that list of elements updating the properties. With no specifics I'm not sure you can have a specific answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done really efficiently by modifying css-rules dynamically. It also makes a lot more sense storing common properties i.e. height for a row of cells in a rule rather than storing it all in each element. And it takes up less memory as well.

With a table-layout like the following:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="row1 col1">data</td>
        <td class="row2 col2">data</td>
        <td class="row3 col3">data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="row1 col1">data</td>
        <td class="row2 col2">data</td>
        <td class="row3 col3">data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="row1 col1">data</td>
        <td class="row2 col2">data</td>
        <td class="row3 col3">data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

We can do something like this:

```
var numRows=3, numCols=3;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(document.createElement('style'));
var sheet=document.styleSheets[1];
//Or instead of creating a new sheet we could just get the first exisiting one like this:
//var sheet=document.styleSheets[0]; 
var selector, rule, i, rowStyles=[], colStyles=[];
//Create rules dynamically
for (i=0; i<numRows; i++) {
        selector=".row"+i;
        rule="{height:20px}";
        if (sheet.insertRule)
            sheet.insertRule(selector+rule, 0);//This puts the rule at index 0
        else
            sheet.addRule(selector2, rule2, 0);//IE does things differently
        rowStyles[i]=(sheet.rules||sheet.cssRules)[0].style;//Remember you have to fetch the rules-array from the sheet and not hold on to the old rules-array, since a new one is created during each insertion. Oh, and IE does things differently again; cssRules instead of rules
}
for (i=0; i<numCols; i++) {
        selector=".col"+i;
        rule="{background-color:white}";
        if (sheet.insertRule)
            sheet.insertRule(selector+rule, 0);
        else
            sheet.addRule(selector2, rule2, 0);
        colStyles[i]=(sheet.rules||sheet.cssRules)[0].style;
}

//Now they can be changed real easy and efficiently like this:
//This line changes the height for the second row, simply by modifying their css-rule, not setting a style-height on each element
rowStyles[1].height="50px";
//It is also really easy to adjust properties of rules added from css-file, just iterate through the rules/cssRules-array checking the selectorText-property of each object until the right one is found.
```

I did a bit of benchmarking and unless I'm going wrong somewhere the difference is quite tremendous. But yeah, apart from the benchmark it really does a huge noticeable difference in the real use case.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>

        <style>
      td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      }
    </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js " charset="UTF-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="table">
            <tr id="row">
            </tr>
        </table>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var tr=document.getElementById("row");
            for (var i=0; i<300; i++) {
                var cell=tr.insertCell(0);
                cell.className="cell";
            }

            var sheet=document.styleSheets[0];
            var c2=(sheet.rules||sheet.cssRules)[0].style;
            var table=document.getElementById("table");
            var startTime;


        //First loop
        startTime=new Date().getTime();
        var c1=$(".cell");
        for (var i=0; i<1000; i++) {
            c1.height(i);
        }
        var time1=new Date().getTime()-startTime;
        //Second loop
        startTime=new Date().getTime();
        c1=$(".cell");
        for (var i=0; i<1000; i++) {
            c1.css("height",i);
        }
        time2=new Date().getTime()-startTime;
        //Third loop
        startTime=new Date().getTime();
        c1=$(".cell");
        document.body.removeChild(table);
        for (var i=0; i<1000; i++) {
            c1.css("height",i);
        }
        document.body.appendChild(table);
        time3=new Date().getTime()-startTime;
        //Fourth loop
        startTime=new Date().getTime();
        for (var i=0; i<1000; i++) {
            c2.height=i+"px";
        }
        var time4=new Date().getTime()-startTime;

        alert ("First:"+time1+" ms\nSecond:"+time2+" ms\nThird:"+time3+" ms\nForth:"+time4+" ms");
        </script>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Would results from this be misleading for some reason? In that case I can't quite see where I'm going wrong so I'd appreciate feedback.
These are the results I get.

**Time taken to complete:**

Loop 1: This one uses a simple jquery class-selector $(".cell").height(h);

- Chrome - 2335 ms
- Opera - 4151 ms
- IE 9 - 3965 ms
- Firefox - 6252 ms
- Safari - 2987 ms

Loop 2: This one is same as above but uses $(".cell").css("height",h) instead. It's faster

- Chrome - 1276 ms
- Opera - 3183 ms
- IE 9 - 2174 ms
- Firefox - 3685 ms
- Safari - 2240 ms

Loop 3: Same as above but it removes the table from DOM before modifying, then re-appending it. Seems faster in Firefox at least

- Chrome - 1259 ms
- Opera - 3079 ms
- IE 9 - 2221 ms
- Firefox - 2872 ms
- Safari - 2250 ms

Loop 4: This one modifies the css-rules dynamically:

- Chrome - 1 ms
- Opera - 10 ms
- IE 9 - 7 ms
- Firefox - 2 ms
- Safari - 13 ms

Comment: Brilliant work there. Changing CSS rules programmatically seems like the way to go. However, I would modify the first three examples  since it seems a little unfair right now that the timer starts before making this jQuery call `c1=$(".cell");`. Doing a DOM search for all matching cells seems unrelated to measuring exactly how long it takes to set a CSS property on those elements.

Comment: Yeah, actually that's how I wrote it first but then changed it. For a static size table we could save $(".cell") to a variable outside the loop as you said, but if new cells might have been added we do have to do it this way. So I guess it depends =). I guess we could put it outside even if the size is dynamic, if we make sure to add/remove cells from c1 when the size changes...

Comment: Ok, I agree that most of the time the DOM search shouldn't be needed. Like when resizing rows. New cells wouldn't be added while the user is resizing. I'll change that later when I'm able to re-do the benchmarks. I bet the difference isn't going to be big though since jquery uses document.getElementsByClassName when available.

Answer (score 1):

When making changes to such a huge structure, it is a good idea to remove it from the document first, so that it only gets re-processed at the end, when you re-insert it.

So, assuming your table is in a variable named `table`, you would do this:

```
var prnt = table.parentNode, nxtsbl = table.nextSibling;
prnt.removeChild(table);
// now do all your modifications, such as looping through rows etc.
prnt.insertBefore(table,nxtsbl);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do table.rows[0] which gives a array of all TDs in that row. Then loop through it and change as wanted

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple if all of your cells are labeled with the appropriate classes.

Say you want to change the width of a certain column.

```
$(".col3").width(newWidth);
```

Or if you want to change the width of a bunch of columns.

```
$(".col3,.col5").width(newWidth);
```

Similarly with

```
$(".row3,.row5,.row9,.row12").height(newHeight);
```

Or if you want to change the background color

```
$(".col3").css("background-color","#ff0000");
```

Comment: The columns could be done MUCH more efficiently with `<col>` tags. Similarly, the rows could be done much more efficiently by working with the `<tr>` tags rather than the `<td>`s within.