# How to Disable a CSS Property and Make It Invalid

Tags: javascript, html, css, invalidation

Okay, so here is the concept. My HTML document has a button that onClick runs a Javascript function. On the web page there are two big divisions, and the purpose of the button is to swap the divisions' places. For example, the one that was on the left goes the right, and the one on the right to the left.

The problem is, the "left" CSS property has dominance over the "right" property, so if both the left and right properties are set to 0 on a div with a fixed width, it will go to the left. Therefore, I cannot get what is on the left over to the right because the "left" property is still present.

I need some way to make the left property invalid, as if I had never even set it so the div will go to the right.

The two divs are called "content" and "navigation" and here is my JS:

```
var order = 0;
var current;
var switchLayout = function() {
    if(order === 0) {
        current = document.getElementById('content');
        current.style.position = 'absolute';
        current = document.getElementById('navigation');
        current.style.left = '0';
        order = 1;
    } else {
        current = document.getElementById('content');
        current.style.position = 'relative';
        current = document.getElementById('navigation');
        current.style.left = 'null';
        current.style.right = '0';
        order = 0;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove css property using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027935/how-to-remove-css-property-using-javascript)

Comment: If you have to set a value, [`left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left) and [`right`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/right) can be set to `auto`.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! I apologize if this was a duplicate.

Comment: Is their container fixed width also? If it was you could just use left on both 'content' and 'navigation' and set one to 0 and the other to the width of the other element.

Answer (score 2):

Dont do your css in Javascript. The easiest way to solve this is have two css classes

```
.left{
 /* styling */
}
.right {
/* styling */
}

var switchLayout = function() {
    var content = document.getElementById('content'),
        nav = document.getElementById('navigation');
    if (content.className === "left") {
        content.className = "right";
        nav.className = "left";
    } else {
        content.className = "left";
        nav.className = "right";
    } 
}
```