# Remove CSS rules by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

How to remove CSS rules by JavaScript?

```
var elStyle = document.querySelector('style#the-style');
var stylesheet = elStyle.sheet;
var rules = stylesheet.cssRules;
for (var i=0; i<rules.length; i++) {
  var rule = rules[i];
  if (rule.selectorText === '#rule2 em') {
    // TODO: remove this rule
    break;
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e3zebmqv/

I succeeded to remove the style by `rule.style.color=''` but the rule still exists. Are there any APIs to remove? Or should I use `innerHTML`?

**UPDATE**

In this case, I'd like to remove style rules, not [style properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027935/how-to-remove-css-property-using-javascript).

(I don't know about Stack Overflow's rule well. I hope this editing was right.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove css property using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027935/how-to-remove-css-property-using-javascript)

Comment: I would recommend changing your CSS rules to be classes and simply replace the class when you want to change it's properties. This way you don't mess with the IDs and can have control over the CSS class output.

Comment: @VladBardalez I added an explaining. Is that OK?

Comment: @iamjpg I'm writing kind of destructor. In this case, changing style is not my goal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

here is an example how you can do this:

```
var styleTag = document.getElementById ("the-style");
var sheet = styleTag.sheet ? styleTag.sheet : styleTag.styleSheet;

if (sheet.cssRules) { // all browsers, except IE before version 9
    for (var i=0; i<sheet.cssRules.length; i++) {
        if (sheet.cssRules[i].selectorText === '#rule2 em') {        
            //console.log(sheet.cssRules[i]);
            sheet.deleteRule (i);
        }
    }  
}
else 
{  // Internet Explorer before version 9
    for (var i=0; i<sheet.rules.length; i++) {
        if (sheet.rules[i].selectorText === '#rule2 em') {        
            // console.log(sheet.cssRules[i]);
            sheet.removeRule (i);
        }
    } 
}
```

And on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n53u7cvm/1/

Comment: [deleteRule()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/deleteRule) is what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

While it is [possible to edit the stylesheet programatically](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/changess.html), it comes with a host of browser problems.

Here is how you obtain the rules from a stylesheet:

```
var rules = new Array();
if (document.styleSheets[1].cssRules) {
    rules = document.styleSheets[1].cssRules;
}
else if (document.styleSheets[1].rules) {
    rules = document.styleSheets[1].rules;
}
```

And if you think that's a bit nasty, it gets worse from there!

## Update

I can see the question has been edited...

The following works ([updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3zebmqv/2/))...

```
if (selector === '#rule2 em') {
    rule.style.color = 'black';
}
```

Comment: I didn't check on old browsers. `.rules` like your codes is required. Thank you.