# element.style.removeProperty("background-color") throwing error Uncaught ReferenceError: cannot assign to function call

Tags: javascript

```
let rating_3 = document.getElementsByClassName("user-rating__rating-number-3")[0];
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: cannot assign to function call in below function @ "HERE"

Why is this error thrown and how to handle this situation ?

I'm new to JS, coming from Java background; it's pretty hard to debug these kind of issues.

```
rating_3.addEventListener("click", () => {

    rating_3.style.removeProperty("background-color") = "";  <== HERE

    rating_3.classList.add("user-rating__rating-number--orange");

    removeClassFromElements(rating_3);

    submit.disabled = false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you assigning it to an empty string

```js
rating_3.style.removeProperty("background-color")
```

just remove the property

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027935/how-to-remove-css-property-using-javascript

Comment: pick one of the 2options, don't use them both.