# Remove Style on Element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering if this is possible.

There's this element

```
<div id="sample_id" style="width:100px; height:100px; color:red;">
```

So I want to remove **width:100px;** and **height:100px;**

the result would be

```
<div id="sample_id" style="color:red;">
```

Any help would be apprreciated. :)

Comment: Check the question tags.... he is asking how he can remove a CSS rule from an element with JavaScript...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [removing html element styles via javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040402/removing-html-element-styles-via-javascript)

Answer (score 219, accepted):

You can edit style with pure Javascript. No library needed, supported by all browsers except IE where you need to set to `''` instead of `null` (see comments).

```
var element = document.getElementById('sample_id');

element.style.width = null;
element.style.height = null;
```

For more information, you can refer to [HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) documentation on MDN.

Comment: Note `null` silently fails in IE11. Use `''` instead.

Comment: Does not work in IE. You should use style.removeProperty() or set to empty string as @OliverJosephAsh commented

Comment: Hint: with attributes which contain a hypen (like `max-width`) you can use this syntax: `element.style.maxWidth = '';` or that syntax: `element.style['max-width'] = '';`

Comment: Style attributes are of type string. Assigning null results in unexpected behaviour. Also Typescript compiler will throw error.  Assign always an empty string to unset the property like mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: As of Sep. 2022 Typescript typing for these style properties, `null` cannot be assigned.  Use `.removeProperty` as @madhu's answer describes.

Answer (score 125):

```
var element = document.getElementById('sample_id');
element.style.removeProperty("width");
element.style.removeProperty("height");
```

Comment: Could you [edit] to explain why this code is correct?

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should always explain how this code helps and what it does.

Comment: I don't know, to me that code is self explanatory... If he had to explain what the code does, he would just reiterate what was asked for in the OP.

Comment: Note that with this approach you use the CSS-style property name in the string rather than the camel case style used elsewhere in JavaScript. For example, you would write `.removeProperty("font-family")` rather than `.removeProperty("fontFamily")`.

Answer (score 8):

Use javascript

But it depends on what you are trying to do. If you just want to change the height and width, I suggest this:

```
{
document.getElementById('sample_id').style.height = '150px';
document.getElementById('sample_id').style.width = '150px';


}
```

TO totally remove it, remove the style, and then re-set the color:

```
getElementById('sample_id').removeAttribute("style");
document.getElementById('sample_id').style.color = 'red';
```

Of course, no the only question that remains is on which event you want this to happen.

Comment: This answer expects you to know what the old style was (aka color = red) Therefor the answer of Blackus is better.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply set that style to [**unset**], It forces CSS to pretend that style was never assigned to the given element.

```js
var element = document.getElementById('sample_id');

element.style.width = "unset";
element.style.height = "unset";
```

Comment: Only one that worked for me

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** For a better approach, please refer to Blackus's answer in the [same thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33039348/2606013).

---

If you are not averse to using JavaScript and Regex, you can use the below solution to find all `width` and `height` properties in the `style` attribute and `replace` them with nothing.

```
//Get the value of style attribute based on element's Id
var originalStyle = document.getElementById('sample_id').getAttribute('style'); 

var regex = new RegExp(/(width:|height:).+?(;[\s]?|$)/g);
//Replace matches with null
var modStyle = originalStyle.replace(regex, ""); 

//Set the modified style value to element using it's Id
document.getElementById('sample_id').setAttribute('style', modStyle);
```

Comment: Everyone is averse to using regex

Comment: Though I understand why this might be useful in some cases, forcing a reparse of the style attribute is inefficient and may no longer be necessary depending on the situation.  ES6 provides destructuring assignment where arrays or objects can be used , e.g. `let assignStyles = props => { const { color, width, height } = props; elem.style = { color, width, height }; }`, compiled once and more efficient, though (much) more verbose, also not practical for dynamic requirements.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#sample_id").css({ 'width' : '', 'height' : '' });
```

Comment: One line solution is always the best

Answer (score 0):

Specifying auto on width and height elements is the same as removing them, technically. Using vanilla Javascript:

```
images[i].style.height = "auto";
images[i].style.width = "auto";
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use like this

```
 $("#sample_id").css("width", "");
 $("#sample_id").css("height", "");
```