# Javascript - Remove the background element - no jQuery

Tags: javascript, dom

So I have this DOM code :

```
<div id="foobar">
    H<br />
    e<br />
    l<br />
    l<br />
    o
</div>
<script>
    var foobarElement = document.getElementById('foobar');
    foobarElement.style.backgroundImage = '';
    foobarElement.style.background = '';
    foobarElement.style.backgroundUrl = '';
    foobarElement.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
</script>
```

With a CSS property on the div :

```
#foobar {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png") repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

(ugly) [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zn2g73rz/1/)

As you can see, I'm trying to REMOVE entirely the `background` attribute CSS (in my example the Google Logo), without Jquery.

In my example, I can't edit CSS, neither write DOM stuff before the `<div id="foobar">`.

NB: all is working fine if in CSS I use `background-image` with the same url instead of `background`

Any idea ?

*Source:*

- [Remove Style on Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691655/remove-style-on-element)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference

Comment: Normally this comment opens with "Welcome to Stack Overflow!", but... :-) Any code related to your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to follow some random link to help you. If the question doesn't make sense and can't be answered without the link, it's not appropriate for this site. Instead, put the [**minimum** complete example](/help/mcve) in the question.

Comment: Well i'm not actually "new" to stack, but ok. A huge amount of question asked here contains only a JsFiddle link, but I understand your point and I will edit my question. And BTW ty for instant downvoting...

Comment: To be honest, I really don't know why downvoting me with close flag : I didn't said "my code is not working, I asked a question, and people answer me. Anyway, I guess running a firm make you big-headed ;)

Comment: 1. Insults are an inappropriate reaction to criticism, particularly clear, polite, and gentle criticism. 2. Never assume the person commenting and the person downvoting are the same person: You'll be wrong **much** more often than right, as in this case: I voted to close for the reason cited above, which is clearly laid out in [here](/help/how-to-ask). I did not downvote, that was someone else, perhaps the person upvoting the comment (or, of course, someone else). But a downvote was reasonable, because invisible code is by definition "unclear."

Comment: 1. Relax, "big-headed" is not an insult.
2. Kindly accept my apologies for thinking "close vote" automatically downvote. My mistake. Case closed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should only use the following code:

```
 var foobarElement = document.getElementById('foobar');
 foobarElement.style.background = 'none';
```

Setting a style property to `''` removes the currently set value and does not set it to an empty one.

The code you have written:

```
var foobarElement = document.getElementById('foobar');
foobarElement.style.backgroundImage = '';
foobarElement.style.background = '';
foobarElement.style.backgroundUrl = '';
foobarElement.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
```

Will result into:

```
<div id="foobar" style="background-color: green">
```

So the `background-image` of your `#foobar` rule is still applied.

If you do just the `foobarElement.style.background = 'none';` then it will result into:

```
<div id="foobar" style="background: none">
```

Which will overwrite the `background-image` set by the `#foobar` rule. Alternatively if you only want to remove the background image then you would use `foobarElement.style.backgroundImage = 'none';`

Comment: Nice one, indeed I didnt though about 'none'... Thank you sir !

Comment: @4wk_ With `css3` there is also the alternative to use `initial` which set the value to the default value defined by the specs, but it is [not supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-initial-value) by IE right now

Answer (score 5):

Little tricky, anyway working fine ,
Use

```
 foobarElement.style.background="0";
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zn2g73rz/9/

Comment: Works too, thanks ! However  I prefer the "none" way ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try following is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/zn2g73rz/8/)

#### Code

```js
function removeBackground(){
 document.getElementById("foobar").style.background= "none";
}
```

```css
#foobar {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png") repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="foobar">
    H<br />
    e<br />
    l<br />
    l<br />
    o
</div>

<button onclick='removeBackground()'>Remove Background</button>
<script>
    var foobarElement = document.getElementById('foobar');
    foobarElement.style.backgroundImage = '';
    foobarElement.style.background = '';
    foobarElement.style.backgroundUrl = '';
    foobarElement.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
div.style.removeProperty('background');
```

```js
div.style.removeProperty('background');
//var foobarElement = document.getElementById('foobar');
//foobarElement.style.backgroundImage = '';
//foobarElement.style.background = '';
//foobarElement.style.backgroundUrl = '';
//foobarElement.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
```

```css
#foobar {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png") repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="foobar">
    H<br />
    e<br />
    l<br />
    l<br />
    o
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I read that `removeProperty` is not supported on all browser. Right ?

Comment: @4wk_ no it supports to most of the browsers, [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/removeProperty)