# How do i change <article> php element style

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build up my own website based on a wordpress template. There's one major problem: article sets up it's own element style in html and i can't find it in style.css or any other file
This is what i get:

```
<article id="post-26" class="post-item post-26 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-uncategorized" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
```

This is my archive.php:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('post-item'); ?>>
```

How do i delete position absolute?

Comment: `article.post { position: static; }` should remove its absolute positioning. If it doesn't, just add `!important` to the rule.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an issue for just a few pages, I use JavaScript get around design issues in WordPress (when the [custom style.css](https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/editing-css/) is not enough).

Edit the page/post where absolute `<article>` is from your dashboard (.../wp-admin). Switch to 'Text' view (not 'Visual'). Insert the following code at the end of any text in the text box.

```
<script>
document.getElementById('post-26').style.position = null;
</script>
```

Here we are just selecting the element using it's ID, and [removing the style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691655/remove-style-on-element) of the `position`.

[Here is a picture of all this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QntF2.png)