# site resolution / zoomed out on mobile

Tags: wordpress

So an old friend of mine who knows nothing about programming asked for help with his site. someone has built it for him long ago, here it is - http://challengetours.org/
The problem is with the site's width. 
As you can see there is a scroll bar at the bottom of the site, which leads to a huge empty space.
There is no problem with that in particular, but when you open the site on mobile it's zoomed-out to see the whole site including the empty area.

what would be the easiest way to solve this ? I have some background but I've never used WP/JS/PHP/CSS :)

Thanks,

Itai

Comment: I should add that I tried many solutions I found online but none of them seemed to make any change. I know too little about WP to have an own idea of what's in this code

Comment: It looks like there's a plugin called Share This, or something similar, that's causing the problem. If you deactivate that plugin it should confirm whether it's the culprit. Manually deleting the iframe going to c.sharethis.mgr.consensu.org and also the div with id "smthemes_share" gets rid of the horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

If WebElaine's comment above doesn't work, you can do the following.

You have two elements setting rules in the CSS:

1. Your div with id `___plusone_0` has an inline style set to `"left: -10000px;"`.
2. Your iframe with the id `st_gdpr_iframe` has an inline style rule of "left: `-5000px;"`.

Removing these two styles gets rid of the scrollbar.

If you are using Wordpress but aren't too familiar with it, you can add your own CSS IDs allowing you to target these elements and override the inline styles if there's an issue with the Wordpress theme itself that you can't otherwise access.

For example:

```
#st_gdpr_iframe{
left: 0px;
}

#smthemes_share .inner{
left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, I think I haven't explained myself enough. What I'm trying to fix is how the site opens on mobile (zoomed out). I tried but nothing changed.. here is a [link] (https://ibb.co/Q8hfYPM) screenshot. again, thanks a lot

Comment: Did you disable Share This, or  delete the rules/apply the above CSS? After doing so I can confirm that it works on mobile as well: http://oi68.tinypic.com/25oxqxg.jpg

Comment: couldn't find the plugin, and I did add the above CSS but it hasn't changed.. it's still the same for me - on Chrome and google search on an android pie phone.

Comment: You could use JS to target those elements and change them. See [Remove Style on Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691655/remove-style-on-element/33039348). You can also use the CSS `!important` rule, although that is typically not encouraged.