# How to select an element style with selenium webdriver

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

I'm having trouble getting a website to show it's hidden parts with selenium. I've tried with old awnsers I found on stackoverflow but they don't seem to work anymore. I also saw developpers solve this problem with requests, but it's not something I'm familiar with.

I'm trying to make visible the captcha token element to automate a website. To make my code I'm training on the google recaptcha demo website (https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo).

I have trouble because in order to show this element I need to click a case in the HTML and I don't know how to do that with selenium.

I've seen people say that in order to display the element I only need to remove the **display : none;** string in the HTML but it doesn't work. The only way I seem to find is to click in the **element.style{** case in inspect element with google chrome.

The HTML part of code of the website I need to interact with is:

`<textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px;height: 40px;border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193);margin: 10px 25px;padding: 0px;resize: none;display: none;"></textarea>`

> you can see the **display: none;** case at the end of the string

When I click that case (I'm putting 2 screenshots so it's clearer for you) it writes this inside the code:

> /* display: none; */

And then the invisible element appears, and i can interact with it.

My question is, how do I make selenium do this? I do get it has something to do with CSS, but since there isn't a litteral opposite to **display: none** I don't know what to do.

Please let me know if I'm not being clear enough.

Thanks

[Element isn't displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvnqt.jpg)

[Element is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNeLI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you can remove style property using javascript. you can tell selenium to execute javascript code for you.

something like this:

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").style.display = null;')
```

---

more info about executing javascript in selenium:

https://pythonbasics.org/selenium-execute-javascript/

more info about removing style properties using javascript:

[Remove Style on Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691655/remove-style-on-element)