# Remove style attribute on style tag

Tags: regex

I have a **STRING** with `html` content. I want to remove `style` attribute on `style` tag with javascript regex, like this:

*before*

`<style style="color: red;">`

*after*

`<style>`

Can you help me ?

Comment: what?? style tag is not visible to browser. I mean it does not render in the page. So why would you have style attribute on style tag?

Comment: There is definitely some missing information here. Why are you using the `<style>` tag like that? That tag is used for defining CSS rules inside your document...

Comment: I'm assuming this is to handle something like code submitted through a CMS or something like that. Stripping out unnecessary attributes.

Comment: $("style").removeAttr("style"); i hope this will do if using jquery..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$input = '<style style="color: red;">';

$output = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i', '$1', $input);

echo $output;
```

Output will be like this

```
<style>
```

Comment: This function is not javascript.

Comment: Well, make it javacript like this: `var input = ''`, `var output = input.replace()`...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have that in a string (this is a very basic example, it will not handle e.g. escaped quotes in property values):

```
str = str.replace(/style="[^"]*"/, "");
```

If that's actually a node in the DOM:

```
node.removeAttribute("style");
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to strip a style-attribute in a string that has HTML-content, with Javascript without making use of the browser (i.e. in a Node environment).

You can use RegEx to remove them.
Either do it only on all tags with a style attribute:

```
// For all tags:
myString = '<style style="color: red;">';
myString = myString.replace(/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/ig, '$1');
console.log(myString);
```

Or just the style tags with a style attribute:

```
// For style tags only:
myString = '<style style="color: red;">';
myString = myString.replace(/(<style[^>]*) style=".*?"/ig, '$1');
console.log(myString);
```

Answer (score 1):

consider the following:

```
var testHtmlString = '<p style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: "Times New Roman";"></p>';
var regex = /style=".*?"\S"/
```

try doing `testHtmlString.replace(regex, '')`

Hope this helps.

Refer this image for proof of answer
[image]

If there is multi line HTML, like you have a large amount of HTML that needs its inline styles removed, use the following -

```
testHtmlMultilineString.replace(/style=".*?"/mg,'')
```

Please refer this image for proof of multi line replace answer:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You put a tag 'javascript' in your question. If you want to use javascript or jQuery, there already exists that question (with solutions):

[removing html element styles via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040402/removing-html-element-styles-via-javascript)

For example, give your element 'id', or 'class' and use:

```
getElementById("id").removeAttribute("style");
```

if you are using jQuery then

```
$("#id").removeClass("classname");
```

Answer (score -1):

That is a ridulous way to use `<style>` but anyway. You can do as this below :

```
var styles = document.getElementsByTagName('style');
for ( var i = 0, l = styles.length; i < l ; i++ ){
    styles[i].removeAttribute('style');
}
```

Fiddle to it works http://jsfiddle.net/xabe7/