# Remove style attributes from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to remove all style attributes from a string (and not an object), in JavaScript or jQuery.

Example

```js
var html = "<p style="color:red">my text</p>";
```

And I want to obtain this:

```html
<p>my text</p>
```

Is it possible to do it without calling the functions that we can call on objects (as `removeAttr`)?

Thanks

Comment: And why do you want to do this using string manipulation, rather than DOM approaches which avoid the edge-cases of using regular expressions to parse HTML strings?

Comment: Cause i never get the full html when putting the string in an object

Comment: you can use regexes on *simple* html strings but heavily nested html is not a good use case for regex.  so it depends, will your html strings be single nodes like the example?

Comment: No my html is much more complex. many levels ...

Comment: then you should parse it like a document and manipulate the nodes with the likes of removeAttr

Comment: But i never get the full html. I have 4 li in ul, and some paragraph tags after, etc. but i only get the 4 li as a result

Comment: You must use regexp, no other way, use this site https://regex101.com/ it helps a lot to understund regular expressions, also this https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions comes in handy

Comment: If you can show the HTML you get, and the end result you want, then we can probably show you how to use a non-regex solution to achieve your requirements. Though regular expressions are capable for simple structures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not looking to use JavaScript or jQuery objects, have you tried using regular expressions?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356398/remove-style-attribute-on-style-tag#19564598) to a previous question shows a php version that can be adapted to JavaScript using the `replace` function.

Answer (score -1):

See if this helps.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("p").removeAttr("style");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p style="color:red">my text</p>

<button>Remove the style attribute from all p elements</button>
```