# Remove Inline Style Element Of a HTML Tag

Tags: html, css, wordpress, styles, inline

I wanted to add a little Menu Hover Animation to my Wordpress Menu:

https://www.littlesnippets.net/blog/some-css-menu-inspiration-using-animated-lines

Somehow my Wordpress Theme (Avada) writes inline html styles to the  tags:

```html
<ul id="menu-menu" class="fusion-menu">
  <li ><a href="#Home" data-hover="Home" **style="overflow: hidden; height: 100px;**"><span class="menu- 
  text">Home</span></a></li>
  <li ><a href="#Events" data-hover="Events" **style="overflow: hidden; height: 100px;**"><span 
  class="menu-text">Events</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

...

I added this Code to my functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'the_content_filter', 20 );

function the_content_filter( $content ) {
    $content = preg_replace('#<a.*?>(.*?)</a>#i', '<a>\1</a>', $content);
    return $content;
}
```

But this removes too much style elements on my page. How can I adjust the function, that only the inline style tags in the class .fusion-menu get deleted?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I wouldn't use regex for html5 because its a loose language. All you have to do is style it with JavaScript again or simply remove the attribute. Better alternative in the long run is to manually edit the themes template to use better specifity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [removing html element styles via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040402/removing-html-element-styles-via-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul#menu-menu li').attr('style', function(i, style)
{
    return style && style.replace(/display[^;]+;?/g, '');
});
```

Please check with above code , It will remove with jQuery

Comment: Introduce an entire library for one simple task? And your selector is not what the OP wants and your Regex will fail with multiple properties and this question is a duplicate and already has an answer

Comment: HTML5 is forgiving :p for example some browsers will accept this as valid syntax `style=“display:none”` but your regex will remove `display:none”` (including the last double quote) leaving `style=“`. Just as an example. Regex is a toughie with HTML5, it’s best not to rely on it if there are alternatives

Answer (score 0):

I've tried already with jQuery but this won't work because I think the function must point exactly on the  tag.

The inline style comes from the fusion builder template but I don't know exactly in wich php file this function lies.

My favourite Method would be when someone could complete my function with the preg_replace with the target of all  elements in selector class .fusion-menu

Thanks...